Is this theory a conservative extension of Heyting Arithmetic ($\sf HA$)?
Consider the following theory over some axiomatixation of first-order $\sf S4$ modal logic with equality:
Universal generalizations of:

$\neg s(x)=0$
$s(x)=s(y) \to x=y$
$x+0=x$
$x+s(y)=s(x+y)$
$x \times 0=0$
$x \times s(y)=(x \times y)+x$
$\Box (A(0) \land \forall y (A(y) \to A(s(y)))) \to A(x)$

Further, this theory is closed under Necessitation:

From $\vdash A$, infer $\vdash \Box A$

and Modus Ponens.

I am aware that some modal systems of arithmetic exist, such as Epistemic Arithmetic ($\sf EA$). I believe that this system is a sub-system of $\sf EA$, but also that it is still strong enough to represent $\sf HA$. Specifically, the induction schema is equivalent to the translation of the induction schema of $\sf HA$. That is, if I’m correct, the literal translation of the induction schema into S4 is the Boxed universal generalization of
$\Box (t(A(0)) \land \Box \forall y (\Box t(A(y)) \to t(A(s(y))))) \to t(A(x))$
where Intuitionistic implication is defined as $\Box (\Box t(A) \to t(B))$ and Intuitionistic univeraal quantification is defined as $\Box \forall x \ t(A)$.
I don’t know if just translating the the $\sf HA$ axioms into $\sf S4$ is enough to yield a conservative extension, and learning how to prove it for this theory would be illuminating to me, so if anyone has any suggestions for a proof that this theory does not add any theorems to the theorems in the language of $\sf HA$, I would much appreciate it.
